# Unclear when to use a specific FactoryGirl syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In the latest release of FactoryGirl, some syntactic methods such as `Factory.create` were depreciated in favor of several others, most notably `FactoryGirl.create` and the simpler `create`.

However, experience shows that certain syntaxes are not always appropriate given the context.

Take for example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :article do
    after_create {|a| a.comments << create(:comment) }
  end

  factory :comment do
  end

end
```

Where Article has_many Comments, and Comments belongs_to Article. In the above factories, `a.comments << create(:comment)` issues the error `Comment(#nnn) expected, got FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static`. Change that line to `a.comments << FactoryGirl.create(:comment)` and the error goes away.

It is not clear when one syntax should take precedence over any other form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I learned the abbreviated notation is not supported in callbacks (such as after_create) as of the current version (3.2.0). This information came directly from the FactoryGirl teams via Google groups. I'll update this question when/if it's added in a future version.

Comment: You're a friggin lifesaver dude. I'm just going to blanket use the long syntax. Better some extra keystrokes than hours of clueless debugging.

Comment: I asked this a year ago, and have been using the long-form since then. Yeah, I agree, way less head scratching.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [FactoryGirl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md), if you want to omit the FactoryGirl module prefix while calling methods like create and build, you need to mix-in FactoryGirl methods in rspec/test-unit module like this:

```
# rspec
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Salil. Yes, I have done that, which allows me to use `create` in only the situations described above.